# p:chart not being rendered

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, charts

I'm trying the following aprouch to display a date-based chart with primefaces:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <ui:composition template="/template/menu.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form>
                <p:dataTable value="#{busca.resultado}" var="serie" style="width:1000px">
                    <p:column>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="3" rows="2">
                            <h:outputText value="#{serie.tipoEmTexto()}" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{serie.nome}" />
                            <h:commandButton value="#{busca.controle[busca.resultado.indexOf(serie)] ? 'X' : '+'}" action="#{busca.flip()}">
                                <f:attribute name="serPar" value="#{serie}" />
                                <f:ajax render="'serie_'.concat(#{busca.resultado.indexOf(serie)})" event="click" />
                            </h:commandButton>
                            <h:panelGroup id="serie_#{busca.meuIndice()}" >
                                <f:attribute name="serPar" value="#{serie}" />

                                <h:panelGrid rendered="#{busca.meuControle()}" columns="2">
                                    <f:attribute name="serPar" value="#{serie}" />

                                    <h:outputLabel value="Extrair" />
                                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{serie.selecionado}" />

                                    <h:outputLabel value="Série #{serie.periodicidadeComoTexto()}" />
                                    <br />
                                    <p:chart type="line" model="#{busca.graficoReal[busca.resultado.indexOf(serie)]}" style="height:300px;width:400px;" responsive="true"/>
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

However, whenever "busca.flip()" is activated and the panelGroup is rendered, no graph is rendered: it simply shows as a blank. This is the creation of the LineChartModel object:

```
private void carregaGraficoReal(Serie s, int index)
    {
        int i;
        LineChartSeries lcs = new LineChartSeries("Gráfico para " + s.getNome());
        LineChartModel lcm = new LineChartModel();
        List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
        DateAxis da = new DateAxis("Datas"); 
        String data;

        ls.addAll(s.getSerieReal().keySet());
        ls = OrdenadoresDeLista.ordenaDatas(ls);

        for(i = 0; i < ls.size(); i++)
        {
            data = ls.get(i);
            lcs.set(dataParaFormatoPrime(data), s.getSerieReal().get(data));
        }

        da.setMax(ls.get(ls.size() - 1));
        da.setTickAngle(-50);
        da.setTickFormat("%b %#d, %y");
        lcm.addSeries(lcs);
        lcm.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setLabel("Valores");
        lcm.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, da);
        graficoReal[index] = lcm;
    }
```

For me, at least, it seem to be all in order with what is stabilished in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/date.xhtml), so I don't have a clue of why it isn't working. I'm running this application in a App Server Glassfish 4.0, JDK 1.7.0, primefaces 5.1 and using JSF 2, if this information might help someone pinpoint why the graph isn't being rendered.

A bit of more information about my code:

- ordenaDatas return a list of strings, which are dates, ordered in crescent order;
- dataParaFormatoPrime turns a string of type "dd/mm/YYYY" in the format "YYYY-mm-dd", as showed in the showcase;
- The panelGroup "serie_x" is rendered correctly for each item of p:dataTable, only not showing the graph;

Comment: i'm facing a similar problem, i didn't have much time to figured out the cause..

But two stepa worked for me:

1) Graph cant be null when the page is rendering for the first time - use a rendered in graph too
2) Try to update your role form with @form

Comment: Still not working for me, saddly. I even tried to just make the LineChart apear on the page without any conditioning of it being rendered or not. Not even this way it would work.

Maybe the problem is with my template.